# HTTParty - how to generate authorisation id from username and password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, ruby-on-rails-3.2, httparty

I use the following curl command on the command line to generate a token id which I then use in the HTTParty code.

```
curl -d "username=Yoshi.Nosaka@test.com&password=testpwd" http://upload.test.org:8026/api2/auth-token/
```

The above curl command generates the token id:

```
6cb2997265877d4cee5467e93577fa
```

I then use the token id in HTTParty commands in my rails application. Example:

```
HTTParty.get("http://upload.test.org:8026/api2/repos/", :headers => { "Authorization" => "Token 6cb2997265877d4cee5467e93577fa"})
```

I would like to know how to generate that token id using HTTParty in my rails app, rather than doing it on the command line.

Thanks a lot for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

cURL -d option send data on a POST.

```
curl -d "username=Yoshi.Nosaka@test.com&password=testpwd" http://upload.test.org:8026/api2/auth-token/
```

I don't know if your app handles json requests. But if so, you can use something like the above.

```
HTTParty.post("http://upload.test.org:8026/api2/auth-token/",
  { 
    :body => [ { "username" => "Yoshi.Nosaka@test.com", "password" => "testpwd" } ].to_json,
    :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'}
  })
```